# Swagger showing no parameters to controller actions that have paramters

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

Swagger **not showing parameters** in UI and JSON, even tho my method has parameters, This particularly happens when I add the **[FromBody]** tag 
[swagger UI no parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLVDF.png)
[JSON file no parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xff2.png) 
The action method:

```
    [HttpPost("Action")]
    public IActionResult Action([FromBody] string message)
    {
        return Ok(message);
    }
```

---

I used fresh Asp.net core **3.1** and **2.2** web app with API template to test this,
I configured it exactly like the [documnetaiton](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#getting-started)  
ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc();

services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
}
```

Configure:

```
 app.UseSwagger();

   app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
 {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
 });
```

---

It does **work** when I use **other attributes** like [FromRoute]&[FromHeader] so on... I looked at the [examples](https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/updatePetWithForm) and swagger does show parameters from a post method

---

I also tried objects like this :

```
    public class Message
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
}
```

With this action :

```
 [HttpPost("Action")]
 public IActionResult Action([FromBody] Message message)
 {
    return Ok(message);
 }
```

same [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKQiO.png) (no parameters) but it does show the schema

---

So what am I doing wrong? how can I document post parameters like the examples

Comment: Any luck with this as I am having the same issue; for the same situation you descibe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into this code sample as you are working with OpenAPI 3.0 : http://petstore.swagger.io:8080/

OpenAPI 3.0 provides the `requestBody` keyword to describe request bodies. It distinguish the payload from `parameters` (such as query string and PATH). The `requestBody` is more flexible in that it lets you consume different media types, such as JSON, XML, form data, plain text, and others, and use different schemas for different media types:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/

That is default UI and if you click "Try it out" , the sample value will auto fill Request body area to help create a test request body .

Comment: This isn't a question about Swagger, it's a question about ASP.NET MVC's ApiController functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on AspNetCore 5.0, where "complex" types would be completely ignored, both as parameters and output types.
The problem was caused by switching input/output formatters to a different JSON serializer (legacy code, due to newtonsoft being slow in certain situations). The new swashbuckle can work either with System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft, but not a 3rd solution.
So check .AddMvcOptions() in ConfigureServices, if there is anything done with InputFormatters or OutputFormatters, that might be the culprit